# How to fix iOS orientation with new API willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

i would like to update my application from deprecreated API

From this one

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
                                         duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
  // Camera rotation needs to be manually set when rotation changes.
  if (self.previewLayer) {
    if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) {
      self.previewLayer.connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientationPortrait;
    } else if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
      self.previewLayer.connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientationPortraitUpsideDown;
    } else if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {
      self.previewLayer.connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeLeft;
    } else if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
      self.previewLayer.connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeRight;
    }
  }
  self.dataOutput.previewFrameSize = self.previewLayer.frame.size;
}
```

to This one

```
- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size
       withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator{
     // CODES HERE 
}
```

The purpose of this change is keep camera's rotation , orientation to be intact. (I'm using EAGL and manual AVFoundation live camera display).

the AV connection still use "Orientation" but the new API didnt offer those one . Anyway to translate it into ??? Thanks

(Swift codes also welcome , my old project written in obj-c but yeah i can read swift)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go one of the two:

```
- (void)willTransitionToTraitCollection:(UITraitCollection *)newCollection 
          withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator;
- (void)traitCollectionDidChange:(UITraitCollection *)previousTraitCollection;
```

Here you get a `UITraitCollection` which has (among others) two properties, `horizontalSizeClass` and `verticalSizeClass`. Those size classes can have a value `UIUserInterfaceSizeClassCompact` or `UIUserInterfaceSizeClassRegular`.

Depending on your device, on iPhone *Compact/Regular* means Portrait, and *Compact/Compact* translates to Landscape.

See [UITraitCollection](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitraitcollection?language=objc) for more details.